# Миграции из двух WebApp с использованием MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion

Tags: c#, entity-framework

У меня есть два WebApp.
Оба обращаются к одной базе, при этом необходимо организовать миграции из обоих App.
У обоих настроена MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion.
При запуске с пустой базой первого приложения происходит создание схемы, в таблицу __MigrationHistory добавляется соответствующая запись, и все ок.
Но при запуске второго второго приложения должны миграция должна внести изменения в существующие таблицы базы, однако приложение падает с ошибкой - "... Данная таблица уже существует". При том это происходит как для таблиц которые были изменены так и для таблиц которые остались неизменны.
Как разрешить данную проблему ?

пример кода второго приложения:

```
Global.asax

Database.SetInitializer(new SyncContextInitializer());                
using (var context = new SyncDataContext())               
{                   
    context.Database.Initialize(force: true);

}

public class SyncContextInitializer :  MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<SyncDataContext, SyncConfiguration>       
{          }

public class SyncDataContext : DataContext      
{               
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)          
    {             
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new IdentityUserLoginMap());             
        .......           
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);           
    }       
}

public sealed class SyncConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<SyncDataContext>        
{
        private readonly bool _pendingMigrations;   

    public SyncConfiguration()            
    {              
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;                          
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;               
        var migrator = new DbMigrator(this);               
        _pendingMigrations = migrator.GetDatabaseMigrations().Any();

    }
    ......
    .....
}
```

Comment: Вы из двух приложений, которые могут быть разными, хотите делать миграции в одну базу?

Comment: да, 2 приложения с общей БД

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что вы создаете одну и ту же таблицу в двух разных миграциях. Это не будет работать.

Если два приложения используют одну и ту же таблицу - они должны использовать один и тот же контекст БД.

Вынесите отображенные на БД сущности, контекст БД и миграции БД в отдельную библиотеку, и подключите ее к обоим приложениям. Тогда все будет работать так, как вы хотите.

---

Альтернативный вариант - не используйте общих таблиц для двух приложений.